Scifi book set in Appalachia with mind-controlling aliens
I'm looking for the title and author for a paperback published probably mid 1990s.
Set in the Appalachian mountains. Main character is young woman trying to avoid notice because she can sense buzzing when one of the Others is nearby, and they can't control her mind. The Others convince her folk she's a witch. They use mind controlled humans to work a mine.
The cover showed a dark-haired girl in a blousy shirt collapsed on a grassy hillside with one arm up to fend off an attack.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are the rest of humanity (who can be mind-controlled) aware of the aliens at all, or are they secret?  Do the miners know whom they are working for?  Is it possible to wake someone up from being mind-controlled?

The rest of the world was unaware, AFAICT. The Others had been controlling the locals for decades, though. Yes, people could be snapped out of the control, but it wasn't easy. The locals thought of the Others framed by superstition, I'm not sure how many knew they were not of Earth.
